# How are SQLServer Timestamp/RowVersion Values Created?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I am relatively fresh to SQLServer's use of `ROWVERSION`/`TIMESTAMP` data, and normally just query for required rows based on modified dates.

How is the `ROWVERSION` assigned to a new row in a database? Does every new row start with the same rowversion, or is it a unique value? In other words, will a new row in the database have its rowversion set to `currentMaxRowVersion+1`?

The use case for this is to query for all rows whose data has changed since the last time the database was queried, EG:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RowVersion > previousHighestRowVersion`

Comment: For your use case, consider [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server). To use `ROWVERSION`, you'd need to save the max value every time the table is queried.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately we don't have access to make changes to the DB. We'll be able to keep track of the `ROWVERSION` when we query the database though, as our software has a mechanism for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing the documentation for [rowversion (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - (highlighting mine)

> Each **database** has a counter that is incremented for each insert or
>   update operation that is performed on a table that contains a
>   rowversion column within the database. This counter is the **database**
>   rowversion. This tracks a relative time within a database, not an
>   actual time that can be associated with a clock. A table can have only
>   one rowversion column. Every time that a row with a rowversion column
>   is modified or inserted, the incremented database rowversion value is
>   inserted in the rowversion column.

---

> You can use the rowversion column of a row to easily determine whether
>   the row has had an update statement ran against it since the last time
>   it was read. If an update statement is ran against the row, the
>   rowversion value is updated. If no update statements are ran against
>   the row, the rowversion value is the same as when it was previously
>   read.

---

As far as being unique - it **'should'** be unique across all tables in a database.  Here is the **'should'** part - there is a caveat in the documentation:

> Duplicate rowversion values can be generated by using the SELECT INTO
>   statement in which a rowversion column is in the SELECT list. We do
>   not recommend using rowversion in this manner.

---

You can check the current database rowversion by using `@@DBTS`.  This example shows `rowversion` in action.

```
set nocount on
drop table if exists mytest
go
CREATE TABLE MyTest (myKey int PRIMARY KEY  
    ,myValue int, RV rowversion);  
GO   
INSERT INTO MyTest (myKey, myValue) VALUES (1, 0);  
GO   
select @@DBTS
go
INSERT INTO MyTest (myKey, myValue) VALUES (2, 0);  
GO  
select @@DBTS
go
update MyTest set myValue = myValue
go
select @@DBTS
go
```

---

```
------------------
0x0000000000009481

------------------
0x0000000000009482

------------------
0x0000000000009484
```

Comment: Thank you. So while new rows won't be `currentMaxRowVersion+1`, they will be able to be found by querying `WHERE rowversion > currentMaxRowVersion`? If duplication does occur, I assume another update on that row will cause the rowversion to increment and become unique again?

Answer (score 2):

There is a single counter for the database. All tables' values will be drawn from this single source. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or update operation that is performed on a table that contains a rowversion column within the database.

This can be shown with a simple example. I'll create a new database and two tables

```
create database DBX;

use dbx;

create table t1(cola int, colb rowversion);
create table t2(cola int, colb rowversion);
```

Adding a row will produce a rowversion value

```
insert t1(cola) values (1);
select * from t1
```

On my system this returns

```
cola        colb
----------- ------------------
1           0x00000000000007D1
```

Your system may produce a different number. The value is hexadecimal, and meaningless.

Adding a row to t2

```
insert t2(cola) values (2);
```

produces this:

```
cola        colb
----------- ------------------
1           0x00000000000007D1

cola        colb
----------- ------------------
2           0x00000000000007D2
```

Repeating produces the expected result, rowversion increments

```
insert t1(cola) values (3);

cola        colb
----------- ------------------
1           0x00000000000007D1
3           0x00000000000007D3

cola        colb
----------- ------------------
2           0x00000000000007D2
```

Note the new rowversion is one more than that in t1.

If I restart the instance and add a row something interesting happens

```
<restart>

insert t2(cola) values (4);

cola        colb
----------- ------------------
1           0x00000000000007D1
3           0x00000000000007D3

cola        colb
----------- ------------------
2           0x00000000000007D2
4           0x0000000000002711
```

The rowversion has jumped significantly. So it is monotonic, but not continuous over an instance restart. Similar behaviour has been observered with SEQUENCES and IDENTITY columns.

So, rowversion can be used to label a "high water" mark in an ETL process. It cannot be used exclusively for a particular table, however. An IDENTITY would be a better choice for that purpose. I have no idea what SQL Server would do if rowversion were ever to overflow.

Comment: It used to be that you got a warning (935) when there were 1,000,000 values left for the timestamp, and after that you can't do any more modifications in the database. That message number is not for something different,makes me wonder if the message was removed when we went from 6 byts to 8 bytes (and "the value will never overflow" mentality)...